# Exporting special characters

Tags: export, character-encoding

I'm trying to export a string with UTF8 characters, but...

```
ToString[{"a" -> "\[Lambda]"}, CharacterEncoding -> "UTF8"]
(* Out: "{a -> Î»}" *)
```

My FE `$CharacterEncoding` is set to "UTF8".

This gives the right value:

```
ToCharacterCode["\[Lambda]"]
(* Out: {955} *)
```

How can I export these characters?

**Edit** `ToString` doesn't behave the same as `ExportString`. @MarcoB's suggestion `CharacterEncoding -> "Unicode"` works for the former, but not the latter.

```
ExportString[{"a" -> "\[Lambda]"}, "Text", CharacterEncoding -> "Unicode"]
(* Out: "ÿþ\"\.00a\.00\"\.00 \.00-\.00>\.00 \.00\"\.00»\.03\"\.00" *)
```

($Version: "10.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (December 4, 2014)")

Comment: Try `CharacterEncoding -> "Unicode"` instead.

Comment: That works, thanks. Am I mistaken that UTF8 should work, though?

Comment: Ugh. See edit; I over-simplified my problem in my original question.

Comment: My understanding is that "All characters are represented internally and in files using Unicode values." (see the "Notebooks" section of [Some Notes on Internal Implementation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/SomeNotesOnInternalImplementation.html#1031388283)). That's why I tried Unicode, and it seemed to work. Let me take another look at the new facet of your problem though.

Comment: Zach thank you for the accept. I tried to add a possible rationale for what you saw in my answer. That was a weird one, but at least I learned something today :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is with your `"Text"` specification, rather than with the `CharacterEncoding` specification. It appears that, when you use "Text", exporting / importing defaults to trying to work with plain text (e.g. ASCII), which fails in the case of special characters.

This shows that specifying `"Text"` is equivalent to asking for `{"Text", "Plaintext"}`:

```
ExportString[{"a" -> "\[Lambda]"}, {"Text", "Plaintext"}] == 
 ExportString[{"a" -> "\[Lambda]"}, "Text"]

(* True *)
```

---

The solution is to **use the `"String"` element** of "Text" instead, which specifies a "raw byte string" (from the [documentation on "Text"](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/Text.html), under "Elements" -> "Data representation elements")

```
ExportString[{"a" -> "\[Lambda]"}, {"Text", "String"}]
```

or more simply but equivalently:

```
ExportString[{"a" -> "\[Lambda]"}, "String"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]