# Displaying Mathematica expressions in plain text

Tags: text, display, character-encoding

I'm trying to export expressions in plain text format, so they can be displayed in a reasonably orderly way (.txt file). Trying:

```
 ToString[a^c/b]
```

yields something like:

```
 c
a
--
b
```

and it does the job. However, when I try to display  $\underset{b}{\stackrel{c}{\sum}}{a}$:

```
ToString[Defer[Sum[a, {b, c}]], TraditionalForm] // ToString
```

I get an Output that seems ok, until I paste it to a text editor, when I get:

```
c  
\[Sum] a  
b
```

Is there a way to overcome this?

Comment: What would you consider an acceptable output for the sum case?

Comment: I'd like to have a sigma symbol in my text enconded in UTF-8 instead of \[Sum].

Comment: Could you check if the technique reported [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/95880/27951) using `CharacterEncoding` works for you? I'm on a mobile device and can't do it myself.

Comment: Plain text and complex math notation aren't really compatible ...  But the `\[Sum]` is correct, just specially encoded. You can `Export[string, "Text", CharacterEncoding -> "UTF8"]` or similar to get a utf8-encoded $\sum$ sign.  Also, don't use `Defer`, use `HoldForm`.

Comment: @MarcoB I tryed, but it didn't work.

Comment: @Szabolcs This worked fine. Although I still have do use `HoldForm` inside f when I want to write an equation, like g=h+i (it interprets as a definition). Is there a way to get away with it? `f[x_] := Export["text.txt", ToString[HoldForm[{x}], TraditionalForm], "Text", CharacterEncoding -> "UTF8"]`

Comment: No, you will need some way of evaluation control. You will also need `SetAttributes[f, HoldAll]` to be able to write `f[Sum[...]]`.  But this may be a hindrance too if you want `x = ...; f[x]`.

Comment: @Szabolcs Funny it works for, say, `f[Sin[a]^2]` but not for `f[Abs[a]]`...

Comment: I wanted to say this, but since things worked for your examples, I didn't ... `TraditionalForm` and `StandardForm` are really for notebooks. They are not for plain text. I would not try to do what you are doing.  If you really must render a large number of formulas *in plain text* using a "natural looking" form, I would look at other tools.  But if I can at all avoid it, I just wouldn't use plain text in the first place...  Use images, MathML, PDF, LaTeX, ect. There are many ways.